# Unwanted tooltip near a box in qlik sense

Tags: data-visualization, business-intelligence, qliksense

I have been getting an unwanted tooltip near a button on my graph.The weird part is it not consistent,It goes off when I refresh.

I have tried searching all along the internet, qlik forums but not help.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image: Picture]

Comment: What type of object is that one. Do you have any extensions / custom javascript installed as in qliksense there is no help text yet?

Comment: The Problem is it is not dependent on any object, I tried getting rid of all objects near it but the thing was still persistent. Also, We do use some custom object called enhanced list.

Comment: It is very, very likely that this is either based on a custom visualization extensions or on a Google Chrome extension triggering this tooltip.
I recommend cleaning the sheet or starting with a new sheet, so that you can more easily identify the evil.
To check whether it is a Google Chrome extension, I recommend the "Incognito Mode in Google".
Furthermore you could just open Chrome Dev Tools, hover over the tooltip, then you'd see where the code comes from.